# Using PDO's odbc to connect to a MSSQL server instance with Windows Authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, windows-authentication, dsn

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL database using PDO with odbc. I'm aware that there's a package `SqlSrv` (but for some reason that package (`.dll`) won't load properly). So I found some documentation arguing it's also possible with PDO. In my `PHP.ini` I've enabled the extension `php_pdo_odbc.dll` and it loads fine.

My connection string looks like this:

```
$conn = new PDO(
    'odbc:
        Driver=SQL Server;
        Server=MyServer\MyInstance;
        Database=MyDatabaseName;
        Trusted Connection=Yes;',
    'MyWindowsUserName',
    'MyWindowsPassword'
);
```

I've tried various properties (for example by prepending the domain to the username, switching with the authentication options User Id, UID, Password, PWD and Trusted Connection) but I keep getting the message

> SQLSTATE[28000] SQLDriverConnect: 18456 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MyWindowsUserName'.

Any suggestions on how to connect to the database with my Windows Account? (that's the only way for me to connect to the database)

Comment: I'd try to figure out why SqlSrv isn't working. It's the "official" way so it would be easier to manage long term.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the username & password

```
$conn = new PDO(
    'odbc:
        Driver=SQL Server;
        Server=MyServer\MyInstance;
        Database=MyDatabaseName;
        Trusted Connection=Yes;'
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (I've already tried it). When I don't provide any credentials it tries to connect as the server's name.

Answer (score -1):

I have authenticated by Windows with following PHP statement:
This is my code:

```
$ Conn = new PDO ("odbc: Driver = {SQL Server}; Server=JAMILI-PC\SQLEXPRESS; null; null");
```

- I am using Windows 2008.
- I hope it solves your problem.